# Array of variables in PowerShell has null members

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have a PowerShell script, where I want to make sure certain variables have value before proceeding.

So I have the following:

```
$dataRow = $sheet.Cells.Find($country).Row
$serverCol = $sheet.Cells.Find($serverString).Column
$databaseCol = $sheet.Cells.Find($databaseString).Column
$userCol = $sheet.Cells.Find($userString).Column
$passwordCol = $sheet.Cells.Find($passString).Column
$partnerCol = $sheet.Cells.Find($partnerString).Column

#All variables in this array are required. If one is empty - the script cannot continue
$requiredVars = @($dataRow, $serverCol, $databaseCol, $userCol, $passwordCol, $partnerCol)
```

But when I foreach over the array like so:

```
foreach ($var in $requiredVars)
{
    Write-Host DataRow = ($dataRow -eq $var)
    Write-Host ServerCol = ($serverCol -eq $var)
    Write-Host DatabaseCol = ($databaseCol -eq $var)
    Write-Host UserCol = ($userCol -eq $var)
    Write-Host PasswordCol = ($passwordCol -eq $var)
    Write-Host PartnerCol = ($partnerCol -eq $var)
    if ($var -eq $null)
    {
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("No data found for given string!")
        $excel.Quit()
        return
    }
}
```

I always get the MessageBox. I added the "Write-Host" part to see the value of each variable, then changed it to see which variable was null but all variables have values in them and all the checks you see here return "False".

I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong and if the `$requiredVars` array only copies values, not references or something.

Comment: A confusing way to write it. Of course, 80% of these statements *will* return false either way.

Comment: Also, you should write `$null -eq $var` instead. Have you tried that? Look here: https://rencore.com/blog/powershell-null-comparison/

Comment: Have you checked values before adding them to the array?

Comment: @montonero, I haven't but could there be a difference?

Comment: @marsze, why is it confusing? If you mean the "Write-Host" bit, that is just for debugging/testing purposes. But still I welcome any advice on improvement. Please divulge.

Comment: You say "all variables have values in them", "I always get the MessageBox" and "all the checks return false". *At least* one of these statements you made *must* be wrong.

Comment: @marsze, Oh, boy, do I feel dumb. The problem was initially I had my array declaration at the beginning, before the other variables had any values in them and I forgot to save my script before running it after I moved it like I have shown in the question.

Comment: I copy-pasted your code and tested it with a simple Excel file and some example values and it worked absolutely 100% fine. The problem is not in the code you posted.

Comment: @marsze, what I meant was - I changed the script. Forgot to save. Ran it. Error. Copy-paste here. Notice mistake. Save script. Ran it. Success. Announce I am dumb. <- You are here, now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using separate variables, you may consider using a Hashtable to store them all.
This makes checking the individual items a lot simpler:

```
# get the data from Excel and store everything in a Hashtable
# to use any of the items, use syntax like $excelData.passwordCol or $excelData['passwordCol']
$excelData = @{
    'dataRow'     = $sheet.Cells.Find($country).Row
    'serverCol'   = $sheet.Cells.Find($serverString).Column
    'databaseCol' = $sheet.Cells.Find($databaseString).Column
    'userCol'     = $sheet.Cells.Find($userString).Column
    'passwordCol' = $sheet.Cells.Find($passString).Column
    'partnerCol'  = $sheet.Cells.Find($partnerString).Column
}

# check all items in the hash. If any item is $null then exit
foreach ($item in $excelData.Keys) {
    # or use: if ($null -eq $excelData[$item])
    if (-not $excelData[$item]) {   
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("No data found for item $item!")
        $excel.Quit()

        # IMPORTANT: clean-up used COM objects from memory when done with them
        [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($sheet) | Out-Null
        # Your code doesn't show this, but you'll have a $workbook object in there too
        # [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($workbook) | Out-Null
        [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel) | Out-Null
        [System.GC]::Collect()
        [System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()

        return
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to directly solve your question is this:

```
$a = "foo"
$b = "bar"
$c = $null

$requiredVariables = $a, $b, $c

# How many total entries in array?
($requiredVariables).Count

# How many of them have a value?
($requiredVariables | Where-Object {$_}).Count

# So one option for a single check would be:
if (($requiredVariables.Count) -ne ($requiredVariables | Where-Object {$_}).Count) {
    Write-Warning "Not all values provided"
}
```

However an alternative [and better] approach is to make your code in to a function that *includes* parameter validation

```
function YourCustomFunction {
    Param (
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    $a
    ,
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    $b
    ,
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    $c
    )

    Process {
        Write-Output "Your function code goes here..."
    }
}

# Call your function with the params
YourCustomFunction -a $a -b $b -c $c
```

Example output:

> Test-YourCustomFunction: Cannot validate argument on parameter 'c'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and 
>   then try the command again.
>   At line:39 char:48

Comment: Thanks, but the point of the script is to read the mentioned variables from an Excel file. I added the validation to check if the read was successful.

Comment: Simple: put the Excel part before the call to your function.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming using you approach the error will only be shown on the command line? Because I have a shortcut that starts my script and the window closes almost immediately after it returns. And I want to keep it that way, that is why I used a `MessageBox`.